# Pair of DatePickers SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a pair of DatePickers in my SwiftUI application which denote the start and end of some time period.

The intended behaviour is that the end date is never before the start date. Thus, the value of `endDateTime` should change when `startDateTime` is changed by the DatePicker. I'm unsure of how exactly to go about this, as I do not believe that `DatePicker` provides something like `onValueChanged`.

**Code**

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var startDateTime: Date = Date()
    @State var endDateTime: Date = Date()

    var body: some View {

        Form {

            DatePicker(selection: $startDateTime, in: Date.distantPast...Date.distantFuture) {
                Text("Start")
            }

            DatePicker(selection: $endDateTime, in: startDateTime...Date.distantFuture) {
                Text("End")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is possible approach (tested & works with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2)

```
Form {

    DatePicker(selection: Binding<Date>(
       get: { self.startDateTime },
       set: { self.startDateTime = $0
           if self.endDateTime < $0 {
               self.endDateTime = $0
           }
       }), in: Date.distantPast...Date.distantFuture) {
        Text("Start")
    }

    DatePicker(selection: $endDateTime, in: startDateTime...Date.distantFuture) {
        Text("End")
    }
}
```